# How would I find a random float from -1 to 1?

Tags: python, random

While trying to define random values to a vector, I found that `random.random()` only gave a number from 0 to 1, and a google search told me nothing more than that. Appreciate the help

Comment: You could do `-1 + 2 * random.random()`, in general you can map to any interval with `min_interval + (max_interval - min_interval) * random.random()`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
import random
random.uniform(-1, 1)
```